# How to block traffic between VMs in the same subnet in Azure other than NSG

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I know NSG can easily do that, but for some reason I can not use NSG, is there any other alternative can do the same? Firewall within VM might also work, but it's better to control that in Azure level, so I don't have to login to the VM so config that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application Security Group (ASG). ASGs are used within a NSG to apply a network security rule to a specific VM or a group of VMs.

You can start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/application-security-groups